# How can I add margin-left and margin-right to an php-element

Tags: php, css, margin

I want to add a margin-left and margin-right to this element. Can anybody help me with that?

```
this.$list.css( 'width', 100 * this.itemsCount + '%' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this should be a jquery question, but...

css() can take a object as a parameter, so try...

```
this.$list.css({
  'width': 100 * this.itemsCount + '%',
  'margin-left': '10px',
  'margin-right': '10px'
});
```